# IS or ARE, when do you use one or the other?

Tags: meaning

The 1% is doing it.

The 1% are doing it.

Which of the sentences is/are correct?

Comment: one percent is singular

Comment: Or you could just rephrase it if both versions sound confusing: *The 1% do it*.